# Issue with Deferred Deep Linking in iOS when run the Facebook live campaign

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ads, deferred-deep-linking

We're trying to implement deferred deep linking in one of our iOS applications  to basically show the product details page when click on the ad but this is not working
Consider the scenario
When the app is not installed and we click on the Facebook campaign ad it should redirect to app store after install of app on open it should redirect to the specify page but it just taking me to first landing page not the specify page. can anyone in the suggest or tell the work around to make it work